# How to install Android support version 13?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I install android support v13 in Android Studio? I've tried searching for it in Dependencies in Project Structure but it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a shortcut to it in the Dependencies tab (Project Structure > Modules > your module name > Dependencies > + button > Library dependency), but from that pane you can type in the Maven coordinates directly:

com.android.support:support-v13:+